# Identifying Sources of Examples in Dahl's Russian Dictionary

Tags: словоупотребление, словарь

Dahl gives two examples of a usage, now surely extinct, of the word фамилия to refer to one's wife, and at least one of them is surely from some novel or the like.  Does anyone have any idea of where these come from?  Or any other examples of this usage?

One is: Cамого я не застал, а видел фамилию их.  The other is: Ваша фамилия, — спросил высокий посетитель приезжего. — В деревне осталась, — отвечал старик простодушно, думая что осведомляются о супруге его.

Comment: https://rus.1sept.ru/view_article.php?ID=200901711

Answer (score 1):

> Does anyone have any idea of where these come from?

The second excerpt is from [Pyotr Vyazemsky, *Старая записная книжка*, entry №146](https://ru.wikisource.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%BA%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B6%D0%BA%D0%B0_141%E2%80%94150_(%D0%92%D1%8F%D0%B7%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9)#146) (or, probably, both from a common source, as it seems to have been a popular anecdote):

> В каком-то губернском городе дворянство представлялось императору Александру в одно из многочисленных путешествий его по России. Не расслышав порядочно имени одного из представлявшихся дворян, обратился он к нему: «Позвольте спросить, ваша фамилия?» — «Осталась в деревне, ваше величество, — отвечает он, — но, если прикажете, сейчас пошлю за нею».

---

> Or any other examples of this usage?

Sure:

> - Г. Беспорядков довольно времени и смотря на меня весьма пристально, и как будто бы желая нечто сказать, морщился, кусал губы, и тем давал мне знать, что не находит материи к начатию разговора, почему я принужденным себя нашел прервать молчание и освободить его от мучения ломать голову над безуспешным изобретением слов и мыслей. "Сколько тому времени, как вы женаты"? — спросил я его.
>   — Уж два года, ответствовал он с видом, изъявляющим неудовольствие, и почесавши затылок.
>   — В добром ли здоровье фамилия ваша? — говорил я.
>   — Беспорядков, — отвечал он сквозь зубы.
>   Признаюсь, много стоило мне труда удержаться от смеха, слыша ответ, совсем не соответствующий вопросу моему; но представив, что он или не вслушался в мой вопрос, или неизвестен о двусмысленности слова "фамилия", употребил я все силы, чтобы вторично сделать ему тот же самый вопрос, только что другими словами.
>   "Здорова ли супруга ваша"? — спросил я его, повысив несколько голос.
>   — Здорова.
>   *[[С. К. Ферельцт. Путешествие критика](http://az.lib.ru/f/ferelxct_s_k/text_1810_puteshestvie_kritika.shtml), или Письма одного путешественника, описывающего другу своему разные пороки, которых большею частью сам был очевидным свидетелем. (1810)]*

---

Dahl made a point of not providing sources for every entry he had gathered:

> … а я-то, сам собиратель, то есть подбиравший крохи эти случайно и сорок лет сряду, на кого я сошлюсь? Или мне выставить при каждом слове: *слышано в городе Ирбити, от купца Пряничникова*, или *в деревне Поповой, Семёновского уезда, Нижегородской губернии, от крестьянки Макаровой*? Ведь краткое указание на губернию, коли слово местное, у меня есть; множество слов, искажённых Областным Словарём, указаны либо исправлены мною, знак сомнения (?) выставлен при каждом подозреваемом мною слове — не знаю, что я мог сделать более?
> *[[И. П. Мельников-Печерский. Воспоминания о Владимире Ивановиче Дале](http://az.lib.ru/m/melxnikowpecherskij_p/text_1873_vospominaniya_o_dale.shtml). (1873)]*

Comment: Many many thanks.  This is extraordinarily useful.  And sorry it took me so long to respond. I have not been well.  Also, since this is for a publication, may I ask just WHO to thank?  Also, the issue is this: Kiparsky claimed that the usage at issue was found in Russian dialects of the former Kazan Khanate and due to Tatar (Turkic) influence simply because  M-P had studied in Kazar.  I propose to critique this assumption.  Anything relevant to this would also be appreciated.

Comment: @AttilathePun: My alias here is Quassnoi, it's fine for the courtesy of. If and when it gets published, could you please add a comment to the post with a reference to the publication? Thank you!

Comment: @AttilathePun: as for the assumption, please make your critique research into an answerable question and post it separately. Thanks!

Comment: Dear Quassnoi, that is the name under which you will be acknowledged then.  It is also not a bad idea to post the substantive question and see if you or another unbelievably knowledgeable, kind, and polite contributor will turn out to know more about THAT too (more than me and certainly more than the great Valentin Kiparsky). Thank you again.